# What value does Starcraft 2 mouse sensitivity refer to?

Tags: starcraft-2, mouse

In Starcraft 2 I can set my mouse sensitivity to some percentage value. What does 100% mean? Is 100% my Desktop mouse sensitivity or the fastest possible speed for my mouse?

I want to have the exact same speed as I have on my Desktop.

Comment: So you question is: How can I get desktop mouse speed in SC2? and not "What value does Starcraft 2 mouse sensitivity refer to?" ? If so, please edit your title.

Comment: Well I want to know both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 100% refers to the maximum speed that Starcraft 2 will move the pointer.

At 50% (with no pointer acceleration) for every one mouse count your computer will move the pointer one pixel on your screen, a 1:1 ratio.

While the slider may read 50% it may actually be set to 49.5% instead. However windows only recognizes 20 different mouse settings which correspond to 5% intervals so this value is rounded down.

By setting SC2's in game sensitivity to between 51%-54% one can ensure that SC2 will be utilizing a 1:1 ratio exactly.

As Ampersand says, disabling "Enable Mouse Sensitivity" results in Starcraft using the OS mouse settings and not the internal SC2 settings.

info/source, some of it cut and pasted from: [Liquipedia II](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mouse_settings)

Comment: So basically the percentage is like the slider in my Windows mouse menu, but it is only for Starcraft 2? Assuming I have my Desktop mouse sensitivity at about 6/10 of the slider and Starcraft mouse sensitivity at 60% would be the same as disabling "Enable Mouse Sensitivity"?

Comment: No. If you set your OS/Desktop mouse sensitivity to 6/10 and the Starcraft 2 mouse sensitivity to 51% would be equivalent to having the desktop mouse sensitivity set to 6/10 and having "Enable Mouse Sensitivity" disabled.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use desktop mouse speed, you should uncheck "Enable Mouse Sensitivity" under Options -> Controls.

Comment: ...and set Control Panel pointer speed in the middle for best results (to avoid skipping pixels), like @chobok said

Comment: ...and disable "Enhanced pointer precision" (mouse acceleration)